# Parsing JSON in Swift with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to return only one part of my JSON data using Swift 4.

This is the JSON I need to parse:

```
{
  "code": 0,
  "responseTS": 1571969400172,
  "message": "TagPosition",
  "version": "2.1",
  "command": "http://123.456.7.89:8080/tag=a4da22e02925",
  "tags": [
    {
      "smoothedPosition": [
        -0.58,
        -3.57,
        0.2
      ],
      "color": "#FF0000",
      "positionAccuracy": 0.07,
      "smoothedPositionAccuracy": 0.07,
      "zones": [],
      "coordinateSystemId": "687eba45-7af4-4b7d-96ed-df709ec1ced1",
      "areaId": "987537ae-42f3-4bb5-8d0c-79fba8752ef4",
      "coordinateSystemName": "CoordSys001",
      "covarianceMatrix": [
        0.04,
        0.01,
        0.01,
        0.05
      ],
      "areaName": "area",
      "name": null,
      "positionTS": 1571969399065,
      "id": "a4da22e02925",
      "position": [
        -0.58,
        -3.57,
        0.2
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "Ok"
}
```

So far I am able to return all of the "tags" array, shown below. However, I just need to return only the "smoothedPosition" data.

```
    func newTest() {
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in

            if let newjson = response.result.value as! [String: Any]? {
                print(newjson["tags"] as! NSArray)
            }
        }

    }
```

Would alamofire be a good way to get the result I want? I previously tried with the Codable method but because there are many different parts to my JSON, I found it confusing to just get the part I need. If anyone could give me some advice on the best way to go about this, I would appreciate it.

Comment: First of all `print(newjson["tags"] as! NSArray)` this line may crash. Please understand a bit about unwrapping optional values in swift. 
Surely, alamofire can do almost everything related to network stuffs in iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Better not to use NS classes with Swift wherever possible. So instead of NSArray use Array.`

To get `smoothedPosition` you need to parse more. `tags` gives you an `array of dictionaries`, so you need to loop array and get each dictionary inside `tags array`. Then finally you can get your `smoothedPosition` array.

```
func newTest() {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response) in
        if let newjson = response.result.value as? [String: Any], if let tagArray = newjson["tags"] as? [[String: Any]] {
            for object in tagArray {
                if let smoothedPosition = object["smoothedPosition"] as? [Double] {
                    print(smoothedPosition)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Also you should read more about `codables` to `parse nested data` and learn about `optional binding and chaining` to prevent crashes when you `force (!)` something which could be nil at some point.
- You can use this site to check the possible `Codable` structure as per your response: https://app.quicktype.io/

Comment: Thank you for this! It works exactly as I need and easy to understand from your explanation and advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good option to create a custom `Codable` struct or class for the JSON response. You may only implement as member variable which you want to reach.

```
struct CustomResponse: Codable {
    let tags: [Tag]
}

struct Tag: Codable {
    let smoothedPosition: Position
}

struct Position: Codable {
   let x: Float
   let y: Float
   let z: Float
}
```

Then

```
Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { (response as? CustomResponse) in
    guard let response = response else { return }
    print(response.tags.smoothedPosition)
}
```

Also you can parse deeper manually your JSON response as stated in the other answers.

Comment: Thank you! It helps me to understand the Codable method better. I will try this method too.

Comment: @lineal Additionally, if you use Alamofire 5 (currently on version 5.0.0-rc.3), you get `responseDecodable`, which will decode `Decodable` types for you.